# Terminfo or termcap in command-line

Tags: command-line, terminal

Is it possible to see a all the capabilities (terminfo or termcap) of the current terminal on command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `infocmp -L -1` to print out a terminfo entry for current TERM.

I'm not sure of an equivalent for termcap but termcap is readable plain text (if you know it's capability codes). I guess you could make use of `captoinfo` in conjunction with `infocmp`

Comment: To be clear: Just `infocmp` also works (the `-I −1` option formats it with one capability per line).

Comment: @ChrisPage: Good point. Actually I meant to write -L not -I, which gives longer names that are easier to understand if you are unfamiliar with terminfo capability names. The -1 aids readability.

Answer (score 0):

To show *all* of the capabilities of a terminal using ncurses, you need different options than were suggested earlier.  The `-L` and `-1` options show long names and a single column, respectively.

Since [release 5.0](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-5.0.html) in [1999](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#other_versions), ncurses has supported *user-definable* (extended) capabilities which may be compiled into a terminfo entry if the [tic](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tic.1m.html) `-x` option is given.  xterm and other terminal entries use these, for additional function key definitions and other features.  There is a summary of these in the [terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_N_C_U_R_S_E_S__U_S_E_R-_D_E_F_I_N_A_B_L_E__C_A_P_A_B_I_L_I_T_I_E_S).

Since [2004](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20040501), [infocmp](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html) has had a comparable `-x` option, which is used to show the extended capabilities.  So you would use this to print *all* terminfo capabilities:

```
infocmp -x
```

You would use `infocmp` with different options to show the terminal description in termcap format, e.g., `-C` (termcap names) and `-r` (termcap format). termcap entries are conventionally limited to 1023 bytes.  However, since all of the data is from the terminal database (terminfo), ncurses can optionally relax that limit, e.g., using `-T`.  Finally, using the `-x` option, infocmp can display user-defined capabilities in termcap format — provided that their names are no longer than 2 characters.